# Adding multiple tuples to a single dictionary key without merging the tuples?

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I am attempting to take a large data set and create a dictionary with multiple data points per key.

For example, I have a list of lists

```
names = [[2013, 'Patrick', 'M', 2566], [2013, 'Mary', 'F', 2602], [2013, 'Alice', 'F', 2915], [2013, 'Alberto', 'M', 581], [2012, 'Patrick', 'M', 2798], [2012, 'Mary', 'M', 6], [2012, 'Mary', 'F', 2559], [2012, 'Alice', 'M', 5], [2012, 'Alice', 'F', 2491], [2012, 'Alberto', 'M', 610], [2011, 'Patrick', 'M', 2858], [2011, 'Patrick', 'F', 5], [2011, 'Mary', 'F', 2700], [2011, 'Alice', 'F', 2190], [2011, 'Alberto', 'M', 660] ......]
```

I attempting to create dictionary such that the result is

```
{ .... 'Patrick':[ ...., (2013, 'M', 2566), (2012, "M', 2798), ...], .....}
```

My first through is to use append such as

```
d = {}
for year, key, gender, count in names:
        d.setdefault(key, []).append(year)
        d.setdefault(key, []).append(gender)
        d.setdefault(key, []).append(count)
```

However, this gives me a dictionary with the data not separated by tuples.

Answer (score 2):

Just append these as tuples.

This should work:

```
d = {}
for year, key, gender, count in names:
    d.setdefault(key, []).append((year, gender, count))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to simplify things a bit.

Your main issue though is that you were appending each element individually, instead append a tuple to the dictionary value (which in this case happens to be a list).

```
from collections import defaultdict

names = [[2013, 'Patrick', 'M', 2566], [2013, 'Mary', 'F', 2602], [2013, 'Alice', 'F', 2915], [2013, 'Alberto', 'M', 581], 
         [2012, 'Patrick', 'M', 2798], [2012, 'Mary', 'M', 6], [2012, 'Mary', 'F', 2559], [2012, 'Alice', 'M', 5], 
         [2012, 'Alice', 'F', 2491], [2012, 'Alberto', 'M', 610], [2011, 'Patrick', 'M', 2858], [2011, 'Patrick', 'F', 5], 
         [2011, 'Mary', 'F', 2700], [2011, 'Alice', 'F', 2190], [2011, 'Alberto', 'M', 660]]

d = defaultdict(list)

for year, name, gender, count in names:
    d[name].append((year, gender, count))
```